# Display table for dyanamically created row in angular 5

Tags: angular

I want to display a table like **[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekyec.png)**, but currently getting a wrong table like **[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMuIN.png)**.

Here's my code -

This is my *user.component.html* -

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> <div
    class="col-md-12">

<table cellpadding="9px" cellspacing="9px">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Jira</th>
            <th>Apllication</th>
            <th>Module</th>
            <th>TestName</th>
            <th>TestDescription</th>
            <th>Projects</th>
            <th>FileChanges</th>
            <th>Impact</th>
            <th>Action</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>

    <!-- <tr *ngFor="let user of users;">
        <td>{{ user.jira }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.application }}</td>

            <td *ngFor="let module of user.module">{{module.module}}</td> 
            <td *ngFor="let module of user.module">{{module.testname}}</td>
            <td *ngFor="let module of user.module">{{module.testdescription}}</td>
            <td *ngFor="let module of user.module">{{module.projects}}</td>
            <td *ngFor="let module of user.module">{{module.filechanges}}</td>
            <td *ngFor="let module of user.module">{{module.impact}}</td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-success fa fa-trash"(click)="deleteUser(user)"></button> </td>
    </tr> -->

    <tr *ngFor="let user of users;">

        <td>{{ user.jira }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.application }}</td>

        <td *ngFor="let module of user.module">{{module.module}}</td>
        <td *ngFor="let module of user.module">{{module.testname}}</td>
        <td *ngFor="let module of user.module">{{module.testdescription}}</td>
        <td *ngFor="let module of user.module">{{module.projects}}</td>
        <td *ngFor="let module of user.module">{{module.filechanges}}</td>
        <td *ngFor="let module of user.module">{{module.impact}}</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-success fa fa-trash" (click)="deleteUser(user)"></button> </td>
    </tr>

</table>
</div>
```

This is my *user.component.ts* file -

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Model, ModuleClass } from '../models/model.model';
import UserService from './user.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-user',
    templateUrl: './user.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./user.component.css']
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
    private users: Model[];

    private user: Model;
    private module: ModuleClass[];

    constructor(private router: Router, private userService: UserService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.userService.getAllUser().subscribe(data => {
            this.users = data;
        })
    }

    deleteUser(user: Model) {
        this.userService.deleteUser(user).subscribe(data => {
            console.log("deleted");
            this.ngOnInit();
        });
    }
}
```

This is my JSON array -

```
[
    {
        "id": "5c1224a0a8355c43745519da",
        "jira": "Jira1",
        "application": "CMM",
        "module": [
            {
                "module": "Nandi",
                "testname": "a",
                "testdescription": "b",
                "projects": "c",
                "filechanges": "d",
                "impact": "e"
            },
            {
                "module": "Sonu",
                "testname": "z",
                "testdescription": "y",
                "projects": "x",
                "filechanges": "w",
                "impact": "v"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**According to this JSON, I need to display the data in the table. Please suggest me the solution to display the data in table format.

I am new to angular. Please let me know if more snippets are needed.

Comment: According to image[1] in that format i need to display the table.

Comment: Image[2] is my current output what i am getting

Comment: post your data structure

Comment: I suggest you create a snippet with https://stackblitz.com to show us your problem and working state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your table body as follows -

```
<tbody>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let userObj of users;">
        <tr *ngFor="let user of userObj.module;">
            <td>{{ userObj.jira }}</td>
            <td>{{ userObj.application }}</td>

            <td>{{user.module}}</td>
            <td>{{user.testname}}</td>
            <td>{{user.testdescription}}</td>
            <td>{{user.projects}}</td>
            <td>{{user.filechanges}}</td>
            <td>{{user.impact}}</td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-success fa fa-trash" (click)="deleteUser(user)"></button> </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-container>
</tbody>
```

**[Here](https://angular-bsxtk3.stackblitz.io)** is a working stackblitz link.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is make use of the `<ng-container>`.
It would look something like:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let module of user.module">
  <td *ngFor="property of module | keyvalue">{{property.value}}</td>
</ng-container>
```

The keyvalue is done to loop through a object. The *.value stand for the value and *.key can display the key.

Answer (score -1):

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzudO.png) is a working snap.

HTML:

```
<table class="table table bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Jira</th>
            <th>Apllication</th>
            <th>Modules</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tr *ngFor="let user of users;">
        <td>{{ user.jira }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.application }}</td>
        <td>
            <table class="table table bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Module</th>
                        <th>TestName</th>
                        <th>TestDescription</th>
                        <th>Projects</th>
                        <th>FileChanges</th>
                        <th>Impact</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tr *ngFor="let module of user.module;">
                    <td>{{module.module}}</td>
                    <td>{{module.testname}}</td>
                    <td>{{module.testdescription}}</td>
                    <td>{{module.projects}}</td>
                    <td>{{module.filechanges}}</td>
                    <td>{{module.impact}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-success fa fa-trash" (click)="deleteUser(user)"></button> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JSON(3 users)

```
users = [
    {
        "id": "xxxxxxxxxx",
        "jira": "Jira",
        "application": "CMM",
        "module": [
            {
                "module": "Nandi",
                "testname": "a",
                "testdescription": "b",
                "projects": "c",
                "filechanges": "d",
                "impact": "e"
            },
            {
                "module": "Sonu",
                "testname": "z",
                "testdescription": "y",
                "projects": "x",
                "filechanges": "w",
                "impact": "v"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "yyyyyyyy",
        "jira": "Jira1",
        "application": "CMM",
        "module": [
            {
                "module": "Nandi",
                "testname": "a",
                "testdescription": "b",
                "projects": "c",
                "filechanges": "d",
                "impact": "e"
            },
            {
                "module": "Sonu",
                "testname": "z",
                "testdescription": "y",
                "projects": "x",
                "filechanges": "w",
                "impact": "v"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "zzzzzzzzz",
        "jira": "Jira2",
        "application": "CMM",
        "module": [
            {
                "module": "Nandi",
                "testname": "a",
                "testdescription": "b",
                "projects": "c",
                "filechanges": "d",
                "impact": "e"
            },
            {
                "module": "Sonu",
                "testname": "z",
                "testdescription": "y",
                "projects": "x",
                "filechanges": "w",
                "impact": "v"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```